# Load a static file in a Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm pretty new to Spring, so apologies if I don't see the obvious answer here.

I set up small demo project with a Spring MVC controller and deployed it to App Engine. In my controller I would like to read the content of a static file into a String. What's the best way of doing that?

I googled a bit but I'm probably searching for the wrong thing. I tried the below, but it does not work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myController")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String myTest() {

        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String content = "";
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader("file:/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            content = bufferedReader.readLine();
            bufferedReader.close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) { 
            // ignore
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Any push into the right direction will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Hell... sure enough, a second after asking the question here I got it working... The correct path in the FileReader should be "WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt" I leaving the question open for now, because I feel, this is not the most elegant way how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation "file:" and "classpath:" isn't right with FileReader.
I suggest you to create a FileSystemResource

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt");
```

and then to use getFile() or getInputStream() to read file.
This is very useful in a web application, because you can use relative path.

Answer (score 15):

Servlet containers in general, and GAE in particular, won't let you use the File API from within the servlet container like that.

Instead, autowire your controller with the `ServletContext`, and fetch the resource from that. Also, your exception handling isn't great, you shouldn't ignore exceptions like that, they're there for a reason.

Something like should be OK:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myController")
public class MyController {

    private @Autowired ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String myTest() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            return bufferedReader.readLine();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
               inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Spring 3.x, this might be even simpler:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/test" view-name="/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt"/>
```

[See docs for what this does](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-controller), but it may mean you can avoid any code.

Comment: Brilliant, that works. Thanks! Regarding the exception handling: 100% agree, I just tried to keep it short because it wasn't essential ;-)

Comment: Is it still legal and best practice if I do this in the `Service` layer? :D

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need encoding conversion introduced by reading a file contents via `Reader` and returning it as `String`?

If no (i.e. if you want to serve a file as is), you can use request forwarding:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View myTest() {
    return new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt");
}
```

or even (if you have `InternalViewResolver`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myTest() {
    return "forward:/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt";
}
```

If yes, note that you didn't specify encoding when reading file, so that system default encoding is used and behaviour of your application is system-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Spring application, you can rely on it's classes to help with this.  In particular, org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource should prove quite useful:

```
ServletContextResource resource = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, 
    "/WEB-INF/content/somecontent.txt");

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: `ServletContextResource` doesn't bring you any benefit here, though; you may as well just get it from the `ServletContext` directly.