# Getting a FileNotFoundException while loading a dictionary text file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filenotfoundexception

```
Context:
```

I have a webapp where I want to provide the feature of auto complete in a text box. I have kept a "dictionary.txt" file in the resources folder of my web app project (the proj structure mentioned below).

```
Web app structure
mywebapp
   |----src
         |----main
                |----java
                |----resources
                       |----dictionary.txt
```

Problem:
I am trying to load the "dictionary.txt" file in the constructor of one of my controllers when the application gets deployed. However I am am getting a FileNotFoundException despite the file being placed there. Please refer the sourcecode below:

```
@Controller    
MyCtrl {    

public String dictionaryFile="dictionary.txt";    

@Autowired
private MyAutocompleteDictTrie dictTrie;

public MyCtrl(){
   DictionaryLoader.loadDictionary(dictTrie,dictionaryFile);
}
  // remaining controller business code here
}

public class DictionaryLoader{
  public static void loadDictionary(MyAutocompleteDictTrie trie,fileName){
    BufferedReader br=null;
    try{
    br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));//exception occurs here
      // remaining business logic here
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to solve this. One possible way is to use `MyCtrl.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)`
But am not sure if that would work while still the application is getting deployed.

Comment: specify the path name also,

Comment: Tried "\\resources\\dictionary.txt" but that doesn't work @Vijay Karchi

Comment: [Refernces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146570/load-a-static-file-in-a-spring-controller)

Comment: Nothing works while the application is being deployed. The application doesn't begin to run until completely deployed. Your reservation doesn't make sense,